# Display selected CoreData value from UITableView in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I've got a `TableViewController` which fetches the `CoreData`. Furthermore if I click on a cell it segues to the `DetailViewController`. But I don't know how I can display the Value in a `UITextView` of the selected row in said `DetailViewController`.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
_managedObjectContext  = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Note"];
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

[_fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];
NSError *error = nil;
[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to perform Fetch");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    
    
    NSArray *objects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

How can I display the value and how do I ensure that the displayed value is the one which I did select in the `TableViewController`?

Comment: I'm sorry but there are tons of step-by-step guides about this

Comment: Did the answer help solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fetch anything in the detailViewController, as the tableViewController already has the object.  Simply pass the text (or the object) to the detail view controller.

Add a property to your detailViewController.  (It could either be an NSString or an NSManagedObject entity.)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detailText
```

In `prepareForSegue:sender:`, set the detailViewController's property to the (text string of) the NSManagedObject associated with the selected row:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)__unused sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        controller.detailText = [object valueForKey:@"myTextProperty"];
    }
}
```

In the detail view controller, assign the text to the `UITextView`.

```
myTextview.text = self.detailText;
```